# Why do I kept getting KeyError:'TURTLEBOT_MODEL' every time I run the teleop command?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do a simple simulation of the Turtlebot3 and I'm currently using ROS2 Foxy. I tried to run this command in the other terminal

```
ros2 run turtlebot3_teleop teleop_keyboard
```

but it returns this error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
```

KeyError: 'TURTLEBOT3_MODEL'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392675/why-do-i-kept-getting-keyerror:%27turtlebot_model%27-every-time-i-run-the-teleop-command?/) by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-12-12**:
Have you done a web search on "TURTLEBOT3_MODEL" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you added TURTLEBOT_MODEL to your .bashrc?
You can do this by writing in the terminal `echo "export TURTLEBOT_MODEL=burger" >> ~/.bashrc` if your model is burger.

---

Originally posted by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) with karma: 170 on 2021-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-13**:
agree that's the issue, unless you source it, you need to `export TURTLEBOT_MODEL=burger` in every terminal.